# How can I rotate map in OpenTTD?

Tags: openttd

**Is it possible to rotate the map?**

Sometimes things are very difficult to select because they are behind buildings or other things.

The shorcut icon, key, etc. would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 24, accepted):

No, I do not believe this is possible. However, you can use `x` to "shadow" objects, which is very useful to solve the problem you are experiencing.

Comment: For finer-grained control, the transparency toolbar (gear menu->Transparency Options) lets you set transparency (or total invisibility) for classes of objects.